# How does deleting words with `d[number]w` work?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

If my cursor is between the words "because" and "and" in the following text, typing **d2w** in command mode deletes everything in between "because" and "su without".

> because and su without

After typing **d2w**

> becausesu without

- Before typing **d2w** there was only one word between "because" and "su" so why were the white space characters either side of "and" also deleted?
- Does **d2w** delete starting from the cursor or after the cursor?
- Why is **d2w** deleting only one word and white space characters surrounding that word instead of deleting 2 words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think of `dw` as delete until the next start of a word.  Likewise `d2w` means delete until the second next start of a word.  It is not the same as "delete a word."

```
because and su without
       ||   \__ 2w
       |\______ w
       \_______ cursor position
```

> Before typing d2w there was only one word between "because" and "su" so why were the white space characters either side of "and" also deleted?

Do the motion `2w`.  Then imagine deleting up until that cursor position.  The only thing that matters is that there are two starts of words (**a**̲nd and **s**̲u).

> Does d2w delete starting from the cursor or after the cursor?

It deletes starting from the cursor, that is to say the cursor character is also deleted.

> Why is d2w deleting only one word and white space characters surrounding that word instead of deleting 2 words?

Because it counts two starts of words forward then deletes everything until that point.

The operation `daw` and `d2aw` can be thought of as "delete a word" and "delete two words."  This might be closer to what you were expecting.

Comment: The part "Because it counts two starts of words forward then deletes everything until that point." is what got me to understand how **dw** works. It's basically delete until start of a word, **d2w** is then delete until 2 starts of words. I didn't know about **daw**, it reads as "delete a word" which is easily remembered, thanks. Although may be you can clarify what is happening in the first diagram?

Comment: `a` means "around" in this case (as in surroundings; not as in approximation).  Compare `ci(` (change in parens) and `ca(` (change around parens).

Comment: @DopeGhoti . You're right that **daw** actually means delete around word because I just found that sometimes **daw** deletes from a space before a word to the end of the word but other times **daw** deletes from the start of a word to a space at end of the word. Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: I'd have to experiment, but I suspect this has to do with cursor position.  Is the behavior consistent if you `daw` with the cursor at the same position relative to the word?

Comment: @DopeGhotti , as an example of **daw**'s inconsistent behavior, the text _"this is a word"_. When the cursor is on a character in the word _"this"_ the result is _"is a word"_. When the cursor is on a character in the word _"is"_ the result is _"this a word"_. When the cursor is on a character in the word _"word"_ the result is _"this a"_